# Which is the app lock that doesn't let you edit other app when the Android is booted?

Tags: android, security

I want an app lock that when I reboot my Android I can't edit settings, because I've used this [DoMobile Lab's AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applockwatcher) and in the first maybe 10 seconds after the phone booted, I can still edit settings (that's the app that I have locked).

Which is the best app lock?

Comment: App locking is not a feature provided by Android, therefore such apps use work-arounds to block access. To block access the locker app has to be active which can take some seconds after a reboot. I don't think that there will be a different app that has no delay after reboot. May be on your device there are just too may apps installed that start directly after reboot so the locker app is getting delayed.

Comment: I have a Xiaomi phone that has the applock function implemented in the system. But the other Samsung phone does not have this function and I must necessarily install an applock and it is the only application installed from third-party sources.The thing is, I like the Samsung phone better because of design.

Comment: If Xiaomi has such a feature then this is because Xiaomi has modified Android. As I told, general Android has no such functionality and adding it afterwards has the problems you already discovered.